# How to show list of missing files and other errors on creating multiple ZIP archives with WinRAR?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, winrar

I made this batch file to create ZIP files based on a text file:

```
@echo off

set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%

for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in (list.txt) do (
    WinRAR a -afzip "%%a" %%b
    pause
    cls
)
```

The file `list.txt` looks like this:

```
file1.zip;fileA.pdf fileB.pdf fileC.pdf
file2.zip;fileA.pdf fileB.pdf fileC.pdf fileD.pdf
file3.zip;fileB.pdf fileD.pdf
file4.zip;fileA.pdf fileC.pdf fileE.pdf
file5.zip;file*.pdf
```

As you can see:

- `%%a` is the name of the ZIP file to create, e.g: `file1.zip` and
- `%%b` is the list of files to add to the ZIP file, e.g: `fileA.pdf fileB.pdf fileC.pdf` for `file1.zip`.

It works very well, but I was wondering if it's possible to make show me which files it **could not** find (and therefore didn't add to the ZIP file) for each ZIP file created.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** As stated by @Mofi, `Rar` cannot be used to create ZIP files. So I changed

```
    rar a -r -m5 "%%a" %%b
```

to

```
    WinRAR a -afzip "%%a" %%b
```

Comment: files not found compared with what reference?

Comment: @Stephan I guess the %%b token would the reference since it's the list of files to add to the ZIP.

Comment: @ItaloSaraiva Do you really want create ZIP archives with console version `Rar`? This is not possible as you can read in text file `%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.txt` which is the manual for console version. Only GUI version `WinRAR` supports creating ZIP archives as documented in help of WinRAR on __Contents__ tab under __Command line mode__. So your batch file produces __RAR__ archives with file extension __zip__. Let us know if you want to create ZIP archives with `WinRAR` instead of using `Rar` and get the errors (missing file and others) displayed in console window.

Comment: @Mofi Oh...I didn't know that. Well I changed `Rar` to `WinRAR` on the batch file and now it's creating **real** ZIP files but it still won't give me any warnings about missing files.

Comment: Perhaps `WinRAR` returns an error code? you could check it by writing `echo %ErrorLevel%` after it; maybe `ErrorLevel` becomes non-zero if (a) file(s) is/are missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console version `Rar` does not support ZIP format as it can be read in text file `%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.txt` which is the manual for console version. Only GUI version `WinRAR` supports creating and extracting ZIP archives.

There is no need to separately test existence of all files to archive on using *WinRAR* as this commented batch code demonstrates:

```
@echo off
rem Define name of error log file in directory for temporary files with name
rem of batch file, an underscore, a random number and file extension TMP.
set "ErrorLog=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

rem Delete error log file if already existing from a previous run of this
rem batch file broke by the user while running and having randomly the
rem same number.
if exist "%ErrorLog%" del "%ErrorLog%"

rem For each ZIP file run WinRAR with ignoring default configuration (-cfg-)
rem using best compression (-m5), running in background (-ibck = minimized
rem to system tray), writing error messages into a log file (-ilog) and
rem suppressing displaying the errors in a GUI window (-inul).

rem If WinRAR really output any error into the log file, clear screen, output
rem on which ZIP file the error(s) occurred, output the logged error messages,
rem delete the error log file, and hold batch processing until user presses
rem any key to continue.

for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in (list.txt) do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip -cfg- -m5 -ibck "-ilog%ErrorLog%" -inul -- "%%~a" %%b
    if exist "%ErrorLog%" (
        cls
        echo Errors output by WinRAR on creating %%a:
        echo.
        type "%ErrorLog%"
        del "%ErrorLog%"
        echo.
        echo.
        pause
    )
)

rem Delete the environment variable for error log file name with path.
set "ErrorLog="
```

For even more details on used *WinRAR* switches

- start *WinRAR*,
- click in menu **Help** on **Help topics**,
- open on tab **Contents** the item **Command line mode**,
- open item **Switches** and
- click on a switch (option / parameter) used in above batch code.

It is important not using `-r` switch (recursive) as this means for *WinRAR* that a parameter after archive name can be a file or a directory.

*WinRAR* v5.21 does not report directories not existing on compression, just files which could not be opened for read because of not existing at all, or no read permission (NTFS partition) for current user, or read/write lock set by other running process on file, etc. The reason for the file opening error returned by operating system is also output by *WinRAR* additionally to error message about failed opening of the file.

*WinRAR* expects without `-r` that each parameter after archive file name is the name of a file (with or without path) and therefore outputs an error message if the file could not be opened for reading the data.

But the parameter can be also name of a directory not existing on using switch `-r` which is not reported as an error by *WinRAR*.

If one or more files in list file contain 1 or more spaces or one of these characters

```
&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
```

in file name it is necessary to quote this file name in list file.

Example:

```
"file 1.zip";"file A.pdf" fileB.pdf "file C.pdf"
file 2.zip;"file A.pdf" fileB.pdf "file C.pdf" fileD.pdf
file3.zip;fileB.pdf fileD.pdf
file4.zip;"fileA.pdf" fileC.pdf fileE.pdf
file5.zip;file*.pdf
file6.zip;file*.pdf readme.txt
```

The archive file name can be also without quotes because of using `"%%~a"` on command line calling *WinRAR*.

The last 2 lines demonstrate that also file name patterns with 1 or more wildcards can be used. But error message `No files to add` is output by *WinRAR* only when ZIP file could not be created because of no file found to add at all. So line 5 produces an error message if there is no `file*.pdf`, but line 6 produces no error message if at least `readme.txt` exists and could be added to archive file.

*WinRAR* sets also `errorlevel` on exit according to page **List of WinRAR exit codes** in help of *WinRAR*. But evaluating the exit code in the batch file does not make much sense if the error messages are output in any case. The error log file is created by *WinRAR* only when any error occurred.

Last but not least it would be also possible to use switch `-log` to get the names of files added to an archive written into a log file and output those list with `type` and `more` in the console window. See help of *WinRAR* for details on switch `-log`.

For understanding the used console commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `type /?`

Answer (score 1):

```
....
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in (list.txt) do ( 

   for %%f in (%%b) do if not exist %%f echo %%f does not exist

   WinRAR a -afzip "%%a" %%b
 ....
```

should show you the missing files.

---

Actual code run to verify:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "u:\sourcedir\t w o"
dir
ECHO ---------------------------------

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=;" %%a IN (c:q33944403.txt) DO (
   for %%f in (%%b) do if not exist %%f echo %%f does not EXIST
   ECHO yourcompressor options "%%a" %%b
   ECHO ---------------------------------
)

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Results:

```
 Directory of u:\sourcedir\t w o

28/11/2015  01:01    <DIR>          .
28/11/2015  01:01    <DIR>          ..
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 dum myfile2.txt
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 file1.zip
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 fileA.pdf
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 fileB.pdf
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 file2.zip
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 fileD.pdf
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 file3.zip
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 file4.zip
28/11/2015  01:05                 0 fileE.pdf
               9 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,134,933,504 bytes free
---------------------------------
fileC.pdf does not EXIST
yourcompressor options "file1.zip" fileA.pdf fileB.pdf fileC.pdf
---------------------------------
fileC.pdf does not EXIST
yourcompressor options "file2.zip" fileA.pdf fileB.pdf fileC.pdf fileD.pdf
---------------------------------
yourcompressor options "file3.zip" fileB.pdf fileD.pdf
---------------------------------
fileC.pdf does not EXIST
yourcompressor options "file4.zip" fileA.pdf fileC.pdf fileE.pdf
---------------------------------
```

Comments:

The directory "u:\sourcedir\t w o\" is simply a test directory. Note that it contains all of the files in OP's list except FileC.pdf

Pushd/popd simply naviages to that directory and back.

The file I used as a source of data (OP's list.txt) was `c:q33944403.txt` which contained the same data as reported in the run report.

So - it works perfectly for me!

Comment: It indeed works now. I guess the problem was the wildcard. Anyways, thanks for your support. I'm picking @Mofi's answer since he pointed out I should use `WinRAR` instead of `rar`.